# Has the kernel panic'd when Ctrl-Alt-F1/F2/...F7 don't work anymore?

Tags: kernel, xorg, keyboard, virtual-terminal

I'm trying to learn (refresh, actually) stuff about X and vt* etc.

I was fooling around, and somehow screwed up, hit a black screen, and even the usual Ctrl-Alt-F1/F2/...F7 to get to a Console didn't work anymore at all (no reaction).

First of all, is my understanding correct that Ctrl-Alt-F1/F2/...F7 is a "kernel" functionality? As in, which code traps Ctrl-Alt-F1/F2/...F7 and.. does something about it?

If Ctrl-Alt-F1/F2/...F7 don't work anymore, has the kernel panic'd and you really have to reboot? Or would ssh in from another machine still have worked (I hadn't tried - and don't know how to screw it up again..) Is there another way to get a terminal to kill.. something to re-establish Ctrl-Alt-F1/F2/...F7 (what) ?

This is just for learning - no actual real life problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. is my understanding correct that Ctrl-Alt-F1/F2/...F7 is a "kernel" functionality ?
   yes.

There's an inherent race condition when switching vt's in an X window envinronment, which would hang the whole system.

It's an ongoing effort to get rid of the archaic vt from kernel, specifically CONFIG_VT.
See [David Herrmann](http://dvdhrm.wordpress.com/) impressive work for more details.

References:
1. [How VT-switching works](http://dvdhrm.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/how-vt-switching-works/)
2. [Sane Session-Switching](http://dvdhrm.wordpress.com/2013/08/25/sane-session-switching/)

Answer (score 0):

To the first question the answer is yes. When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F?</kbd> you are invoking a particular virtual console. In a text console you only need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F?</kbd>, but to be consistent with the X session it will yield the same behaviour with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F?</kbd> combination.

When these key combinations stop working usually it means something when very wrong. It can be a kernel panic but also hardware failure or an hardware induced lock. The later releases of kernel 2 used to lock on [Sandy Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandy_Bridge) architectures.

In essence, if you reach a state where you can't switch virtual consoles a reboot is most likely your only way out.